# that brother of John

Tags: meaning, possessives

Can one say

a. I am thinking about that door of the house which is locked.

b. I am thinking about the door of the house which is locked.

c. I am thinking about that brother of John who is a doctor.

d. I am thinking about the brother of John who is a doctor.

?

Does (d) show that the speaker doesn't like that brother of John or not?

Is it disparaging towards the person in question?

Many thanks.

Comment: It’s hard to say for sure, but most native speakers would say “John’s brother,” not “the/that brother of John.”

Comment: Contrasting *How's your brother?* and *How's that brother of yours?*, I'd say that although the latter is *likely* to imply "disdain" for the brother on the part of the speaker, this isn't necessarily the case. You can tell this because it's also quite natural to ask things like *How's that **wonderful** brother of yours?* The effect of including ***that*** is to emphasise the "unusual, remarkable" nature of the referent in some context-relevant way. There would be very few (contrived) contexts where this could work in example (a) above, which looks decidedly "odd" to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you ask about disparagement, I assume you're referring to **that**, as in **That brother of yours!**.

As FumbleFingers comments, its meaning is context-dependent.

> That brother of yours is one fine musician.
>
> That brother of yours is such a smart-ass. He shows no respect.
>
> That brother of yours is always getting into mischief.
>
> That brother of yours, what crazy idea won't he think up next!

The locution singles out the brother as a topic of conversation. The brother is being pointed at, so to speak, and the speaker is going to point out something about him.

Comment: I think you've nailed it with *singles out the brother as a topic*. It doesn't necessarily imply singling out ***that** brother* as opposed to *any **other** brothers*, as can be illustrated by the fact that one could say this to someone who *has* no other brothers. And you could even say something like *That paraffin-wax teapot cosmology of yours sounds interesting*, where (I hope! :) there's no suggestion that you're identifying one of *many* "paraffin-wax teapot cosmologies". But in practice the net effect feels like one of "emphasis", regardless of the "literal" meaning.